# iOS Swift - Accessing method in Child from Parent

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

In my app I have a Storyboard with a bunch of elements laid out. I am setting properties  of these elements from "ViewController.swift".

On the storyboard are two UIViews, which have been subclassed to allow for drawing methods. They are to be used as "signature" fields, where a user can sign their signature into the box. This is working fine.

One of the subclassed methohds of the UIViews is "eraseBitmap" which clears the UIView of the drawing.

```
class SigView: UIView {
    ...
    func eraseBitmap() {
        path = nil
        cache = nil
    }
}
```

I have a button that calls a function "erase" in the parent VC.

I have tried doing

```
func erase() {   
    SigView.eraseBitmap()
}
```

However that generates an error saying that I'm missing an argument. eraseBitmap, however, accepts no arguments.

If I add an argument, regardless what it is, I get a "SigView not convertible to..." error.

Any ideas, or a better way of coding this part?

Comment: What is 'SigView'? The name of a class?  The name of an instance of a class?

Comment: SigView is the class name of the subclasses UIView. Edited OP to add a bit of clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SigView` class defines a method `eraseBitmap()` - something like:

```
class SigView : UIView {
  func eraseBitmap () { /* ... */ }
}
```

You'll apply this method to instances of `SigView`.  So, somewhere you've got an instance of `SigView` in your UI, like:

```
var aView : SigView = ...
```

You'll then use:

```
func erase () {
  aView.eraseBitmap()
}
```

or perhaps

```
func erase (view:SigView) {
  view.eraseBitmap()
}
```

The error you are getting is caused by attempting to invoke a non-class method on a class.  Non-class methods can only be invoked on instances of classes.

Comment: Thanks. I realized I was declaring my var in the parent VC as :UIView instead of :SigView